# Google Translate — how to force a translation via javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-translate

We have a partial translation via a language file but have many dynamic elements that we would like to use Google Translate to translate for us.

Is there a way to initiate a translation via javascript without the user having to select from the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, visit following link

http://support.jimdo.com/tutorials/apps-and-plugins/how-to-add-google-translate-to-your-website/

Comment: Thanks for this but the question is not 'how can I add a google translate widget to a site' but how can I force a translation programmatically via javascript without requiring a user to make a selection from the google widget. Thanks

Comment: You can use the Google Translate API to programmatically translate text in your webpages or apps. But that I think costs you!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely translate the dynamic elements by picking them up and passing it to the **[Google Translate API using a REST request](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest)**. And you can get the response in JSON and extract the translation from it.

For example as shown below:

> **Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&target=zh-TW
```

> **Response**

```
200 OK

{
    "data": {
        "languages": [
            {
                "language": "zh-CN",
                "name": "中文(簡體)"
            },
            {
                "language": "fr",
                "name": "法文"
            },
            ...
            {
                "language": "en",
                "name": "英文"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

See more examples at [Google Translate API - Using REST](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, yes I am aware of the API..its very cool and will take complete HTML content but its a paid for service. I was hoping there was a way to 'simulate' a user selecting a new language from the normal google translate dropdown (which isnt actually a drop down) by triggering an event in javascript.

Comment: Okay Robert. Let me see if I can come up with some solution to help you in that.